# How can I deploy a React Project with a node.js backend on an Ec2 instance to the web securely?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a plain react app that makes called to a backed on an ec2 instance that is running via pm2. It is using express. I have tried uploading my project to aws amplify but then I ran into an issue. My calls from the amplify site were not https so it would't display any of the server information as it wasn't secure. I saw that I may need a "load balancer" and some ssl but I don't know how to implement those changes. Locally, the project works perfectly.

I have already tried AWS Amplify and also tried running everything from the ec2 instance and accessing that but it did not work.